# Is there in Eclipse any function like autofill breakpoints in all projects?

Tags: java, eclipse

There is some java-screen-app with buttons. Debug is configurated for switch screens connection from DB for local PC. 
There are many projects in source of debug on local PC, but if I delete one or more project, then debug will use same projects from test-server.
I need to find point in code, where process starts by the buttom click.

By the way I have another way to find this point, but it isn't simple.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to find out which Java code is executed by a specific user action?

Comment: Yes, but action isn't difined in my components

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **find which Java code is executed by a specific user action** you can use the **differential code coverage** function of ***[EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/)*** (included in the [latest Eclipse Java packages](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/)):

1. [Launch your Java application in coverage mode](http://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/launching.html)
2. Reset already collected coverage data by dumping coverage data with the option *Reset on Dump* (see [*Dump Execution Data* button in the *Coverage* view](http://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/coverageview.html))
3. Execute the function in your application
4. Dump the coverage data again

Result: The code that has been executed by the function is shown as covered.

Watch [this video from 17:41 for a demonstration](https://youtu.be/p_mVa9iNmzk?t=17m41s).

Comment: Nice answer, Thank You, but this development attached to the Eclipse Luna by plugin for special version control system.
However, this information can be useful in another project)

Comment: You can use _EclEmma_ also with _Luna_ (maybe not the latest version but an older version). _EclEmma_ became part of the Eclipse Java packages when it became an Eclipse project. But it can also be installed in older Eclipse versions. The update site is for all Eclipse versions the same: `http://update.eclemma.org/`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the variable name of the button?  If so you could do a search of that variable name to try and track down the ActionListener for that button.

Comment: button defined in DB. I don't want to search them their, because if I go this way I'll need to find buttons name in DB, then servise name in other DB, then component name and method in 3rd DB.