# Debug from an unknown place in code with Eclipse, is it possible?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I need to debug a desktop app in Eclipse that has complicated structure and doesn't give me an exception. But it surely doesn't work right.

Can I somehow run it in debug mode and proceed to some suspected place, and then get to current line of code like to a breakpoint if I had it there? Or pause right on the next call.

Seems not a big deal, but I cannot find it.

Comment: yes, you can walk through the execution of a program via a debugger...I mean, that's the whole concept of a debugger, isn't it? Set a breakpoint at the beginning of the program, then step though it

Comment: [Eclipse Debugger](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/june/article1.php)? Put the breakpoints in the lines you suspect are not working properly, the IDE can't do that for you.

Comment: AKSW if I start with a breakpoint, I won't get to the problematic place in a long long time.

Comment: deHaar, the application I have to fix is very big, like 50 projects with their own packages and so on. I just cannot do that blindly

Comment: If you cannot describe where to stop in code, how debugger will knows it?

Comment: Bor Laze, i need it to pause on the next method call. What's so difficult about it?

Comment: @Bobby but If you even cant specify what is wrong and where with the application how should the debugger know?

Comment: I want it to set a breakpoint on the very next method call. Whatever that method is. This is how I want it to work. Is there such a feature in Eclipse?

Comment: You can use differential code coverage to find the code that is executed when using the suspicious feature: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46104503/6505250

Comment: "if I start with a breakpoint, I won't get to the problematic place in a long long time" You can check and un-check breakpoints when program is running, or add a condition or a hit count to a break point.